# Passing multiple arguments to async - Python multiprocessing

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I am trying to run a function which requires multiple dataframes as arguments. I need this to run in parallel given the time to execute.

Given the volume and size I need to ensure that the multiprocessing of the function is passed the data so memory doesn't explode. I've tried the following, please could someone help me figure out how to pass the split data and dataframes 1 - 3 in the loop correctly?

The current code just freezes and raises an assertion error.

```
try:
    for batch in split_data(data, size=10000):
            p.apply_async(function_applied, ([batch], data1, 
    data2, data3))

finally:
        p.close()
        p.join()
```

NB: The 'split_data' function separates pandas dataframes into the size specified.
data1, data2 ... etc are pandas dataframes

Comment: What is the assertion error that it raises?

Comment: It doesn't raise a specific error, however here is the traceback: 
File C:\Users..... line 337, in _get_more_data
assert left > 0 
AssertionError

Hope this is helpful..

Comment: `function_applied` accepts 1 argument, a tuple?

Comment: It accepts the following; batch, data1, data2, data3